# handling single and double quotes php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hello all i am having a project where a user can write any comment on any post currently everything is going very good i mean that the user can post and comment successfully but when the user comments any line which contains any single or double quote the whole text is just skipped nothing is displayed .
like the text i'll call you is not displayed but i will call you is displayed 
i know i need to use addslashes but i don't know how to use it.
i tried to addslashe after the post variable and then send it to database bit nothing happens

here is my form and code

JS

```
function formsubmitionbyajax(obj){
        $.ajax({ type: 'post',
        url: 'home_formhandler1.php',
        data: $("#postform").serialize(),
        success: function(){
        $("#LOADreftraed").load("Mypage.php #LOADreftraed");
        $("#postform")[0].reset();
}   } );    return false;   }
```

PHP action page

```
 $views=$_POST['views'];
 $comment=$_POST['comment'];
 $onid=$_POST['onid'];
 $onemail=$_POST['onemail'];

  $insertposts=mysql_query("insert into `fk_views` (`views`,`session_id`,`email`,`Date`) 
  values    ('$views','$sid','$email','$time')");
   exit;
```

i have many forms like this and is there any way to addslash to all the post variables and then send them to BD
please help me .

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string  would do that . no?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated have a look at PDO

Comment: @nbin where to use it on the action page ??

Comment: @Sedz will change it to mysqli later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like

```
$views=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['views']);
```

[for more see documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: and while printing it i should use strip slashes ??

Comment: you don't have to use strip slashes.

Comment: then the comment displayes like i\'ll call you insted of i'll call you

Comment: Oh.Once it's on db then, while printing you can do whatever you think is appropriate.

Comment: @anamika  To show in html you can use htmlspecialchars(). info in doc